# Javascript Console window missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, office-addins, visual-studio-2019

I am debugging an Office Add-in. When I attach the debugger and select Visual Studio 2019 as the debugger target, the debugger successfully attaches and I can inspect the DOM.  However, there is no option in the `Debug` or `Debug -> Windows` menu to open the Javascript Console window like there was in VS 2017.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems Javascript console window has been removed in VS2019. Please check [vs2019 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#dotnettools).

- **The ability to use JavaScript Console functionality in ASP.NET
  projects has been removed. We recommend that customers use Console
  included within their favorite browser devtools.**

In addition: Other member has submitted a feature request: [Bring back javascript console](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/514147/bring-back-the-javascript-console.html). You can vote for it and if it gets enough points, the product team would consider it.